# Using return statement inside java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Hi have two implementation some piece of code where I am modifying the strings using Java stream:

```
final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("abc");
strings.add("bca");
strings.add("xyz");

Method 1:
final List<String> modifiedStrings = strings.stream().map(a -> {
        String abc;
        abc = a.replace("a", "*");
        return abc;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

Method 2:
final List<String> modifiedStrings2 = strings.stream().map(a ->
        a.replace("a", "*")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to know if there is any performance difference between method one and method two.

Comment: Probably no difference. You have 1 extra reference defined in method 1, which is what - 8 bytes? - and this will probably get in-lined after compilation.

Comment: Did you try and measure any difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. This will compile to essentially the same bytecode. The second version is just a more concise way to write it.

Example code:

```
void foo(List<String> strings) {
  strings.stream()
      .map(
          a -> {
            String abc;
            abc = a.replace("a", "*");
            return abc;
          })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

void bar(List<String> strings) {
  strings.stream().map(a -> a.replace("a", "*")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Corresponding lambda bytecode:

```
  private static java.lang.String lambda$bar$1(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: ldc           #8                  // String a
         3: ldc           #9                  // String *
         5: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/String.replace:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/String;
         8: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 18: 0

  private static java.lang.String lambda$foo$0(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: ldc           #8                  // String a
         3: ldc           #9                  // String *
         5: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/String.replace:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/String;
         8: astore_1
         9: aload_1
        10: areturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 11: 0
        line 12: 9
```

So, the bytecode is not *quite* the same - there is an extra `astore_1` and `aload_1` in the `foo` case; but this is likely irrelevant, as it can just be optimized away.

Comment: @Thilo ah, yeah. Gimme a sec.

Comment: @Thilo actually, they don't compile to the exact same bytecode: there's an extra `astore` and `aload` in the `bar` form. Sigh. Apologies for jumping in to edit your answer. Please do with my contribution what you choose.

Comment: Since the question’s title focuses on the `return` statement, it’s worth pointing out that `a -> a.replace("a", "*")` and `a -> { return a.replace("a", "*"); }` *do* generate the same bytecode. It’s just the introduction of an additional local variable which, well, creates code using an additional local variable.

Comment: and that extra local variable (which is low-cost to begin with) will probably get optimized away by the JIT. So worrying about this being a difference is really silly (even if it does not get optimized away).

Answer (score 1):

When the body of a lambda function is just one single expression the compiler determines the [return type and value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) from this expression.

It is just syntactic sugar.